# Run windows local program from remote linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script, ssh

I'm trying to run a python script on a remote linux machine accessed by SSH from my local Windows machine. The script contains a loop where for all files in a directory it's going to go to a certain directory on my local windows and run the command line based program. I am not the root user and it's going to be fairly difficult to install anything on the linux machine.

The basic error that I get is that the remote linux machine can't find the C: directory on my windows. I plan on a running a loop for all files in a certain directory.

My Windows is 64bit and the linux machine is 64bit Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to transfer the script to the linux machine, so before `ssh`ing to the remote server `scp` your script to -lets say- /tmp and then `ssh` and execute the file that should be in the linux machine's /tmp directory.

Comment: Yes, I have uploaded to the remote machine server. When I run the script, it says 'C:/'(local windows) not found.

Comment: Then it may help have your script's code posted so that someone can check it (not me I don't know python).